# gmail send error 'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required

Tags: vb.net, google-api, gmail

I know there are other questions like this here and this is a common error, but I happen to know that I'm doing everything right (famous last words), so.... I have .net code I wrote years ago that sends mail using the gmail api, works great.  So I ported (copied more like) it over to a new web service (still in .net) and I get this error.

`'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required`

This message seems to want me to use the /upload/ variant of the URL

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/{address}/messages/send`

instead of the one I am using:

`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{address}/messages/send`

I can only surmise this is because it thinks I am trying to upload media?

Now this *exact* code works in a different project, so my thought is something is different, and I have no doubt that is the case, but I have quadruple checked every line (and there's not that many) and I see nothing different.

So prior to this I have the permissions, scope, access and refresh tokens, all that is needed to send using the gmail api. Do it every day, no problems.

Build the msg:

```
        Dim msg As AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        msg.Subject = pSubject
        msg.Body = pBody
        msg.From = New MailAddress(emailSetup.Address)
        msg.To.Add(New MailAddress(pTo))
        msg.ReplyTo.Add(msg.From)
        success = GmialSend(msg, access_token)
```

GmailSend:

```
        Dim msgStr As New StringWriter()
        msg.Save(msgStr)
        Dim rawBody As String = Utility.Base64UrlEncode(msgStr.ToString())
        Dim client As New RestSharp.RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com")
        Dim request As New RestSharp.RestRequest("/gmail/v1/users/" & emailSetup.Address & "/messages/send", RestSharp.Method.POST)
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & access_token)
        request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json
        Dim ojson As New JsonRequest(rawBody)
        request.AddJsonBody(ojson)
        Dim response As RestSharp.RestResponse = client.Execute(request)
        Dim email_response As String = response.Content
```

JsonRequest:

```
 Public Class JsonRequest
     Public Property raw As String = ""
     Public Sub New(s As String)
        raw = s
     End Sub
 End Class
```

So this code works in one project, but in my new project it fails with the above message.  Since it is 'working' code I don't know what to change to make it 'work' here.

I used nuget to load AE.Net.Mail and RestSharp and have the <s>same versions</s> and the same version of .net (4.0).

EDIT: RestSharp is new version 106.11.7, working copy is 105.2.3

Is there any way to tell just what about the request it is that the api does not like? I could rewrite the whole thing but this code is working and has worked for years...

EDIT: Added the api error response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalidArgument"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Like all things that don't seem right they are not.  I ran the old original code locally and I get the same error...so that begs the question: what am I running on my server?, why is this code different?, and what is wrong with this code?  I have not changed this project in a long time...need to dig through the archives.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: the code that works uses RestSharp 105.2.3, the code that does not work uses RestSharp 106.11.7.  Why does 106.11.7 not work? I don't know. Setup exactly the same as shown above. Anyone know how to get 106.11.7 to work in this case, I would like to know.